# extracting numbers after matching a string

Tags: bash, unix, sed, awk

I have a CSV log file that looks like:

```
{"locale":"en_US","action":null,"name_id":4820951,"time":80239874928,"focus":disabled,"end_data":false}
```

I only want to extract what comes after `name_id` so the output would be 4820951.  Is there a way to do this with sed or awk?

I'm new to unix scripting so would appreciate any help.

Comment: That doesn't seem `CSV` data.

Comment: all the rows are in that syntax. I saved it as csv because each category is separated by a comma

Comment: Just because it uses a comma for a separator doesn't mean it's CSV. In this case, with the braces, colons and quoting, it appears to be a bit more JSON-ish...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And a pretty simple `awk` solution too.

```
awk -F: '/name_id/ {print $2}' RS=, file
4820951
```

Answer (score 2):

It is pretty simple with `grep -oP`:

```
grep -oP '"name_id" *: *\K\d+' file
4820951
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a really funny solution:

This seems to be [json](/questions/tagged/json). So why not use a JavaScript interpreter? If you're running gnome-shell, you have `gjs` installed (if not, you may have a JS interpreter too; or not). With `gjs`:

```
gjs -c 'var disabled="disabled";print({"locale":"en_US","action":null,"name_id":4820951,"time":80239874928,"focus":disabled,"end_data":false}.name_id);'
```

I had to define `disabled` so that it works.

Neat, eh?

If you have a full file full of similar lines:

```
while read -r l; do
    printf -v c 'var disabled="disabled"; print(%s.name_id);' "$l"
    gjs -c "$c"
done < file
```

It's not the most efficient, but you'll be sure the data is always well parsed. `:)`.

You can try with `rhino` instead of `gjs`, but `rhino` is much slower. YYMV.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with:

```
awk -F[,:] '{ 
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i+=2) { 
        if ( $i ~ /name_id/ ) { 
            print $(i+1)
            break
        } 
    } 
}' infile
```

It yields:

```
4820951
```